# Regex that consists of one or more capitalized words or integers, separated by spaces

Tags: regex

So the general outcome should be 'Test 123 Hello Hi' I used regex101 and the logic says I'm doing it correctly however I can't seem to get it to correctly limit the text.

```
^(([A-Z][a-z]*)|([0-9]+)\s)+
```

Comment: what would be input?

Comment: a string. The correct input as I said would be 'Test Example 123 Hello' Failure would be 'No lower Cases allowed'

Comment: Give us sample that should pass/fail but it does not

Comment: Pass:
'Test Example 123 Hello'
Fail:
'Test example 123 hello'

Comment: and which one does not work as expected?

Comment: two problem in your regex: 1. depending on your usage, you may need to have end-of-line anchor ($) at the end.  2. your alternation is wrong: it is now `((a)|(b)\s)` but I think you want `((a|b)\s)` instead

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

(Doesn't have to end with a space)

```
^((([A-Z]([a-z]*))|([0-9]+))\s)*((([A-Z]([a-z]*))|([0-9]+)))
```

(Has to end with a space)

```
^((([A-Z]([a-z]*))|([0-9]+))\s)+
```

Comment: 'Test test' passes but shouldn't. All words should be capitalized.

Answer (score 1):

You can test your scenario by running following expression :

```
^(\b([A-Z]|[0-9])\w*\s*)+$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\b([A-Z][a-z]*|[0-9]+)\s?)+$
```

Explanation

```
^                                 start of line
 (                                group 1, which represent one group of word
  \b                              word boundary
    (                             a group of 
     [A-Z][a-z]*                    capitalized word 
                |                   or
                 [0-9]+             bunch of digits
                       )          end of group
                        \s?       followed by optional space
                            )+    group 1 happening at least once
                             $    end of line
```